# How to blend cubemaps in Unity Shader Language

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, skybox

Hi fellow Unity devs,

I have been trying to modify the built in Unity shader for Skybox/Cubemap, such that it takes a second cubemap, and has a blend factor between the two.

I have attempted the following shader script, however it does not produce the intended result, is anybody who knows more about shader code than me please able to assist in my learning/results? I am finding it very difficult to learn how to use shader code, only been using Unity for about 2-3 months.

```
Shader "RenderFX/Skybox2" {
Properties {
    _Tint ("Tint Color", Color) = (.5, .5, .5, .5)
    [Gamma] _Exposure ("Exposure", Range(0, 8)) = 1.0
    _Rotation ("Rotation", Range(0, 360)) = 0
    _Rotation2 ("Rotation 2", Range(0, 360)) = 0
    _Blend ("Blend", Range (0, 1) ) = 0.5 
    [NoScaleOffset] _Tex ("Cubemap   (HDR)", Cube) = "grey" {}
    _Skybox2 ("Skybox two", Cube) = ""
}

SubShader {
    Tags { "Queue"="Background" "RenderType"="Background" "PreviewType"="Skybox" }
    Cull Off ZWrite Off

    Pass {

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma target 2.0

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        samplerCUBE _Tex;
        half4 _Tex_HDR;
        half4 _Tint;
        half _Exposure;
        float _Rotation;

        float3 RotateAroundYInDegrees (float3 vertex, float degrees)
        {
            float alpha = degrees * UNITY_PI / 180.0;
            float sina, cosa;
            sincos(alpha, sina, cosa);
            float2x2 m = float2x2(cosa, -sina, sina, cosa);
            return float3(mul(m, vertex.xz), vertex.y).xzy;
        }

        struct appdata_t {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
        };

        struct v2f {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float3 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata_t v)
        {
            v2f o;
            float3 rotated = RotateAroundYInDegrees(v.vertex, _Rotation);
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(rotated);
            o.texcoord = v.vertex.xyz;
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            half4 tex = texCUBE (_Tex, i.texcoord);
            half3 c = DecodeHDR (tex, _Tex_HDR);
            c = c * _Tint.rgb * unity_ColorSpaceDouble.rgb;
            c *= _Exposure;
            return half4(c, 1);
        }
        ENDCG 
    }

    Pass {

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma target 2.0

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        samplerCUBE _Skybox2;
        half4 _Skybox2_HDR;
        half4 _Tint;
        half _Exposure;
        float _Rotation2;
        float _Blend;

        float3 RotateAroundYInDegrees (float3 vertex, float degrees)
        {
            float alpha = degrees * UNITY_PI / 180.0;
            float sina, cosa;
            sincos(alpha, sina, cosa);
            float2x2 m = float2x2(cosa, -sina, sina, cosa);
            return float3(mul(m, vertex.xz), vertex.y).xzy;
        }

        struct appdata_t {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
        };

        struct v2f {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float3 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata_t v)
        {
            v2f o;
            float3 rotated = RotateAroundYInDegrees(v.vertex, _Rotation2);
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(rotated);
            o.texcoord = v.vertex.xyz;
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            half4 tex = texCUBE (_Skybox2, i.texcoord);
            half3 c2 = DecodeHDR (tex, _Skybox2_HDR);
            c2 = c2 * _Tint.rgb * unity_ColorSpaceDouble.rgb;
            c2 *= _Exposure;
            return half4(c2, 1);
        }
        ENDCG 
    }

    Pass {
        SetTexture[c]
        SetTexture[c2] { 
            ConstantColor (0,0,0, [_Blend]) 
            Combine texture Lerp(constant) previous
        }       
    }
}   


Fallback Off

}
```

The result is a grey view, and I don't think I am passing the c/c2 variables properly, or even if they CAN be passed like that. I am really stumped as to how I might achieve this effect.

The blend pass works fine for just the plain textures, but I need it to maintain the rotation values, not just the textures.

Thank you in advance to you shader/Unity experts out there! I hope one day to join your ranks.

Comment: why do you have two same pass ?

Comment: Hi @Tengku, that would be due to my inexperience with shaders. I simply copy pasted the same default skybox/cubemap shader pass, however it passes in the second cubemap

Comment: i see, if that so try this link, http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SkyboxBlended , hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! 

However, I have seen that shader and don't think it is what I am seeking. It uses a 6 texture skybox as opposed to a cubemap, and therefore would also not assist in maintaining a "rotation" value that may be applied to cubemap skyboxes.

Comment: did you try look at lerp() function? i never try blend skybox, but for material and others i just add another variable and just lerp between those two.

Comment: Hi @Tengku, the material.lerp function does not affect the texture of the material unfortunately, just some of the values set within it. Something I haven't tried yet, is to get the pixels of the material.MainTexture, and lerp between those (if I can do that). If I get the opportunity today I will try that and let you know the results, just depends on my workflow as other office jobs are taking priority over this task at the moment. :)